# Is it good practice to have the same function names in multiple header files?

Tags: c, header

I'm writing a userland in C (be it minimal at the moment) and I'm making it like BusyBox where you can run a command by invoking a symlink with its name. I've got a "main" C file which includes all the other files inside it (the other files are header files) and then runs their code if the symlink name matches. I was wondering whether it is deemed OK to have functions with the same name across different header files?

For example, if I had `thing1.h`:

```
void help(void)
{
    // Print help text for thing1
}

int thing1(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (something)
        help();
}
```

And `thing2.h`:

```
void help(void)
{
    // Print help text for thing2
}

int thing2(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (something)
        help();
}
```

And `everything.c`:

```
#include "thing1.h"
#include "thing2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (something)
        thing1(argc, argv);
    else
        thing2(argc, argv);
}
```

Would it be better to rename those help functions to `thing1_help` and `thing2_help` respectively, or is it OK to leave them as they are?

Comment: Why don't you compile your sample? If your compiler says it's not ok, you'll have to accept that, no matter what random guys on the internet think about it.

Comment: Why is there code in header files? That's bad practice.

Comment: No; it is not a good idea to repeat the `help()` function in two headers.  Think SPOT — Single Point of Truth; also think DRY — Don't Repeat Yourself.  And embedding actual code in headers is not a good idea, either.  You should only do that for `inline` functions, and only if you know what you're up to.  Otherwise, headers should contain only declarations, not definitions, of variables and functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, please understand more how the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) works and read also the [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/).

Notice that preprocessing is a purely textual operation. So you could avoid having any header files and `#include` directives, e.g. by copy-and-pasting things. That would be a bad idea.

So header files are mostly a *conventional* thing (however, the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard does mandate some standard headers, like `<stdlib.h>` or `<stdio.h>`; and [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) specifications also mandates several headers). Common practice includes:

- wrapping the header file contents with an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) (to disable multiple inclusion)
- putting only *declaration*, not *definition* of (often "global") functions, types, variables in header files.
- putting the definition of `static inline` functions in header files.

Actually, *standard* header inclusion (e.g. `#include <stdlib.h>`) could even in principle be implemented without any `stdlib.h` textual *file* : the compiler implementation could for instance query a database to process `#include <stdlib.h>`  directive, but I know no compiler doing that.

Some people (me included) are putting `#include` directives (notably for standard C99 or Posix headers) inside their header files. Others are documenting the list of headers to be included before their own header files.

Look at the preprocessed form of your code (which is what most of the compiler care about, since the preprocessor is the first phase of the compiler). You could obtain the preprocessed form of `everything.c` using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with

```
 gcc -C -E everything.c > everything.i
```

Then look inside `everything.i` with an editor or a pager.

In practice, I would suggest to make -if it is really short- your `thing2` a `static inline` function, then to have a *single* (not several) header:

```
// file thing.h
#ifndef THING_INCLUDED_
// declarations
void help(void);
int thing1(int argc, char *argv[]);
// definition:
static inline void thing2(int argc, char**argv) {
   if (something_with(argc, argv)) 
      help();
} 
#endif /*THING_INCLUDED_*/
```

then put the *definitions* of `help` and of `thing1` in e.g. your `everything.c` and add there an `#include "thing.h"` after the others `#include` directives.

Answer (score 1):

Both help functions should be the respective c files then it wouldn't matter that there's a name clash as they are private to the scope of that compilation unit.

In general keep code in c files and only declarations in h files.